# phpmailer attachment not working on form submit

Tags: php

This is my php code for sending mail with attachment.

```
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
$message1 = '<html><body style="width:70%;border:1px solid #000;">';
$message1 = 'Some html';
$message1 .= "</div></body></html>";

$emailnew = new PHPMailer();
$emailnew->From      = 'info@test.com';
$emailnew->FromName  = 'test';
$emailnew->Subject   = 'Thanks For Downloading';
$emailnew->Body      = $message1;
$emailnew->IsHTML(true);
$emailnew->AddAddress( 'some@gmail.com' );
$emailnew->AddAttachment( 'test.pdf' );
    if(!$emailnew->Send())
{

   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
else
{
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

The attachment file is in the same directory as that of phpmailer class but iam just getting the message there is not attached pdf in it..
But if i execute the same code in test file then it is working fine.
I tried to provide the full path also but still it did not resolve my problem.

Comment: No. You need to place the pdf file on the same folder as the page you included the phpmailer.php class. That is suppose, send_mail.php is the name of the page consist of this code you pasted. Then the attachment has to be on the same folder of send_mail.php

Comment: @AeJey `require_once` pretty much says that class file and the script page are in the same folder. And since pdf is in the same folder as the class file, it would mean all 3 are in the same folder

Comment: @AeJey I have the pdf file in the same folder infact everything is in same folder.

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice that. :P

Comment: @amit this makes no sense if you say `But if i execute the same code in test file then it is working fine`

Comment: So let's say the test file's name is `abc.pdf`. You're saying that `$emailnew->AddAttachment( 'abc.pdf' );` is working while `$emailnew->AddAttachment( 'test.pdf' );` is not?

Comment: @asprin I used the same code in another file but there it is working fine. but in this after sending mail iam redirecting the page is that a problem??

Comment: @asprin No. thats not wat iam trying to tell.

Comment: if you are redirecting via `header("Location:...")` after successfully doing `$emailnew->Send()` it should not be the problem.

Comment: ok, you said all files are in the same folder. But: are you calling the files directly from your browser or are you including these files from another file located somewhere else? The path to  `test.pdf` should be relative to the file which is called in your browser or should be the absolute path of your server.

Comment: @steven Iam using relative path of test.pdf , file called by browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after digging for hours i found out the solution.
Actually i had changed the working directory to include some files from root folder.

```
chdir('../');
```

This was the problem i was not able to locate the attached file.